# Setting breakpoints in RStudio during package development

Tags: rstudio

I am developing a package in RStudio and would like to use breakpoints to debug my functions. However, I keep running into the same problem: I set a breakpoint, RStudio warns me that the package has to be built and reloaded to activate the breakpoint (even if I just built and reloaded the package), and then when I build and reload the package the breakpoint disappears.  Is there something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

move your `.R` file to the directory that `.RData`  exist and then 
`setwd("directory of .RData file")`.

this solution worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a bug that was solved by closed and re-launching RStudio.  I discovered that I was also having a problem with my saved datasets (in data/) not loading. So, I believe something was wrong with the package build and reload in RStudio that was solved by restarting the software, and this was what caused the strange breakpoint behavior.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue at the moment... is there anything else you changed to get it working again?

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem, and restarting RStudio didn't solve it for me.
One workround is to put `browse()` before the code that have error as a breakpoint, it will stop there and you have an interactive session to check the problem.

[This](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) is a very thorough article explaining all debugging options available in RStudio. I found it really helpful.

Comment: Browser() worked for me as well, whereas setwd() and restarting did not.  It would be interesting to know exactly how setting breakpoints is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to the fact that I had placed copies of the .R file in the R folder of the package. I made those files to keep the minor changes for a while.
It seems that the breakpoints will be overwritten by the other functions, that has the same name as the function I intended to set the breakpoints, defined in other .R files.